# How to implement upwards-flow display of text messages in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a chat-style display of text messages where the first line would appear at the bottom, and then any new additional subsequent text always appear at bottom and moving any previous lines upwards.

For example:

1st line appeared:

```
Me: Hello!
```

2nd line appeared:

```
Me: Hello!
Friend: Hi, there! How are you?
```

3rd line appeared:

```
Me: Hello!
Friend: Hi, there! How are you? 
Me: Great, what about dinner this weekend?
```

(Problem: In a standard TextView, text would start appearing at the very top of the view. I'd like the first line of text to appear at the very bottom, with each new addition moving the previous ones upwards.)

So, how do I implement this? Is that a standard widget which I use or a library?

Comment: `Problem: In a standard TextView, appending text to the view would be added to the bottom`

Is this a typo? Isn't appended text going to the bottom exactly what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. I've edited that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiment, here is the solution to make text appears from the bottom first:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/outputTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#666666"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This has resolved my problem!